# R: Recreate a 3D mesh plot

Tags: r, plot, 3d

How would I recreate the following plot in R?

[image]

I'm struggling with generating data, given that the Z-coordinate is determined with the following equation:

[image]

where

[image]

A vectorized solution would be good, and a 3D, interactive plot would be even better.

I have the following:

```
## generate the data points from a multivariate normal
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
Sigma <- matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=100,mu=c(10,10),Sigma=Sigma)) # X1=x, X2=y

theta0 = theta0 <- seq(-5,5,by=0.5)
theta1 <- seq(-5,5,by=0.5)
z = NULL
m <- theta1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a prototype to get you up and running using the `rgl` packages. If you want other interactivity that rotating then something else needs to be pursued. Also, some of the stuff is hard-coded below (variables names and df) so that could be improved

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
Sigma <- matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=100,mu=c(10,10),Sigma=Sigma)) # X1=x, X2=y    
theta0 = theta0 <- seq(-5,5,by=0.5)
theta1 <- seq(-5,5,by=0.5)

# Produce J
f <- Vectorize(function(t0, t1) { sum((t0 + t1*df$X1 - df$X2)^2)})
z <- outer(theta0, theta1, f)

# Get the rgl library and plot
library(rgl)
persp3d(theta0, theta1, z, col="lightgray", smooth=TRUE)
```